# Run X11 apps in Docker container using MacPorts' Xorg-Server on macOS host

Tags: emacs, docker, xorg, macports

I'd like to run the Emacs code editor in a Ubuntu Container I installed in Docker, and I'd like to run it in GUI mode.

I installed the `xorg-server` port using MacPorts, but it defaults to a Unix-domain local socket, which is inaccessible in the container (due to security settings).

How can I run container apps using host X11? Is there a way to setup a IP (v4 or v6) socket for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the X11 App, in preferences, the security tab, check the 2nd box to allow network connection.
2. Use `xhost` (install from `port` if you haven't) to set the auth setting to allow it.
3. Set the `DISPLAY` environment variable in the container to `${IP_of_the_Host}:0.0`

And Bob's your uncle.